# Manytomany field is None and can't create or add field to model. How do I add the field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

My models are set up as follows:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         related_name='person_user')
    type = models.IntegerField()

class Score(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person')
    score = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I can create Score objects fine and create a relation to the Person. However, the next part is causing some difficulty. I added Score after I had already created the following fields (except for the very last line):

```
class Applicant_Response(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                      related_name='user')
    interview = models.ForeignKey(Interview, related_name='interviews')
    extra_information = models.ForeignKey(ExtraInformation, related_name='extra_information', null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.ManyToManyField(Score, related_name='applicant_score', default=1)
```

I created a Score object that had a score of 0 and a person to use as the default for score (was assigned an ID of 1). However, when I tried accessing the field score in the Applicant_Response, I get profiles.Score.None, which confuses me (profiles is the name of the application).

To my understanding, I am not able to add anything to the manytomany field because it does not exist? Maybe the way I am trying to add Score to Applicant_Response is incorrect?:

```
try:
    applicants = models.Applicant_Response.objects.filter(interview=interviews)
    for applicant in applicants:
        applicant.score.add(models.Score.objects.get(id=1))
        applicant.save()
        print applicant.score
except Exception as e: print e
```

I get the following in stdout: profiles.Score.None

How do I add a Score to the Applicant_Response object?

Answer (score 0):

I find out [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
# You have to Save() first.
applicant.save()
applicant.score.add(models.Score.objects.get(id=1))
# I think it work???
# If not:
sc1 = models.Score.objects.get(id=1)
applicant.save()
applicant.score.add(sc1)
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: this does not work. I get the same output as described in the question

Comment: did you save first???

If save ~> have application ~> Try to print it,

Then ~> try to create and add Score. Just give it more try and short this later